# share dict between processes

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I spawn a seperate process to handle my cloud services. I spawnb it like this:

```
CldProc = Process(target=CloudRun)
CldProc.start()
```

and am wondering if I can have a shared dictionary between that CloudProc and my current main process?

*EDIT:*
Alternatively I am thinking to use pickle to dump my data into a file from the process and load it back, this requires me to use join() to wait for the process to complete and exit.

*2nd EDIT*
So, I now have my dict declared like mac_dict={} and then I fill it in my subprocess and want to access it in my main process. Now I just tried this:

```
>>> dict = dict()
>>> dict['A'] = 1
>>> print dict
{'A': 1}
```

So how does Python know that dict() should be called from Managers?
Is there any examples I can follow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it, to simplify, I did it like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def myf(myd):
    myd[1] = "HELLO WORLD!"

def proc(d):
    myf(d)

m=Manager()
locdict=m.dict()
locdict[2] = "HI BUDDY!"

p = Process(target=proc, args=(locdict,))

p.start()
p.join()
print locdict
```

Comment: Glad to assist ... I was just about to come up with an example but you seem to have gotten it.

Comment: It's worth noting here, that you do not have to pass locdict to the target function proc. The function myf will change locdict successsfully if you just did locdict[1] = 'blah' from it's body.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`multiprocessing.Manager`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) and the [`Manager.dict()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict) method in particular.  They may serve your needs.